# How to custom arrange such that no group dimension contains the same index twice?

Tags: r, algorithm, tidyverse

I have the following tibble containing all the permutations of some indexes:

```
bb <- as_tibble(expand.grid(v1=0:2, v2=0:2)) %>%
  arrange(v1, v2)
bb
# A tibble: 9 x 2
     v1    v2
  <int> <int>
1     0     0
2     0     1
3     0     2
4     1     0
5     1     1
6     1     2
7     2     0
8     2     1
9     2     2
```

How can it be arranged in such a way that it generates this output instead:

```
     v1    v2
  <int> <int>
1     0     0
2     1     1
3     2     2

4     0     1
5     1     2 
6     2     0

7     0     2
8     1     0
9     2     1
```

Where the output is three groups/sets such that within each set there is no repetition of the index within each variable. Note that there can be only so many rows per group/set fulfilling this criteria ...

Comment: How do you decide the groups/sets ? Is it always fixed (3) or some formula based on number of rows ?

Comment: @RonakShah `0:(N-1)` thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that I am not very familiar with `tibble`, so I provide a solution with `data.frame` in `base R`:

```
shifter <- function(x, n) ifelse(n == 0, return(x), return(c(tail(x, -n), head(x, n))))

res <- `rownames<-`(Reduce(rbind,lapply(seq(length(dfs<-split(df,rep(0:2,3)))), 
                                        function(k) {
                                          dfs[[k]][,2] <- shifter(dfs[[k]][,1],k-1)
                                          dfs[[k]]})),seq(nrow(df)))
```

which gives:

```
> res
  v1 v2
1  0  0
2  1  1
3  2  2
4  0  1
5  1  2
6  2  0
7  0  2
8  1  0
9  2  1
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(v1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), v2 = c(0L, 
                                                                        1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                              -9L))
```

***Update***: a more efficient generator for all combinations with desired format is given as below:

```
genAllCombn <- function(n) {
  v1 <- rep(0:(n-1),n)
  v2 <- (v1 + rep(0:(n-1),1,each = n)) %% n
  return(data.frame(v1,v2))
}

> genAllCombn(4)
   v1 v2
1   0  0
2   1  1
3   2  2
4   3  3
5   0  1
6   1  2
7   2  3
8   3  0
9   0  2
10  1  3
11  2  0
12  3  1
13  0  3
14  1  0
15  2  1
16  3  2
```

Comment: thank you for the time you took to prepare this answer but the result is incorrect. Each group must not repeat indices e.g. in your answer's first group v2 is `0,0,0,0` so it repeats `0`.

Comment: @SkyWalker sorry that I made a mistake in my function `shifter()`. I updated my solution and result, so it seems the right one now, please check it out

Comment: Cool idea with shifting, I wish it could be made simpler using `tidyverse` ... I will think about it.

Comment: @SkyWalker I wrote a generator for construct the output as you need, please see my update, which is significantly more efficient, I think.